# Dealing with incomplete types

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

I have two classes: one of them has an incomplete type, and the second needs to use that incomplete type. Is there any way to reference an "external type", in a manner similar to how you reference an external object?

---

**Edit:** Details about the structure of my classes.

Unfortunately I can't use pointers either. My code looks something like this:

```
class CompleteA {
  private:
    friend CompleteB;
    struct IncompleteA;
    boost::shared_ptr<IncompleteA> data_;
};

class CompleteB {
   public:
     void SomeFct(CompleteA& a) {
        // I need to access a member of the incomplete type
        a.data_->someMember;
     }
};
```

I could have a separate header and source files pair but the that would be a bit of an overkill in my case. The incomplete type is just a struct with one member; I use it to hide the implementation. (However, if there's no other option, I will resort to having a separate header...)

About my use of friend, please ignore that and concentrate on what I'm asking help with. I've pondered about whether or not I should use friend here and I've come to the conclusion that using getters (instead of a friend) would expose the implementation.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  You may want to post an example of what you are trying to do and then someone may be able to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Since CompleteB is a friend, I don't see why you don't use a private getter in CompleteA (which gets implemented somewhere else), like @Matthieu M. suggests. There is absolutely no problem here, pimpl idiom with incomplete types is common, and this is the way you bridge into the implementation of the pimpl class.

Answer (score 6):

Use forward declaration.

In your yourotherclass.h:

```
class IncompleteClass;

class YourOtherClass
{
    IncompleteClass* member;
};
```

In your yourotherclass.cpp you will actually need to include the incompleteclass.h in order to be able to use the pointer.

Edit: responding to your details:

If you want to hide the implementation, create a separate (friend) class for that and reference that:

```
class CompleteAImpl
{
    friend CompleteA;
    // data, members, etc. that you intend to hide
};

class CompleteA
{
    CompleteAImpl* priv; // or shared_ptr if you want
};
```

I think you wanted to do something like this. The problem with your implementation is that in order to reference a member a struct/class the compiler needs to to know the size of that member and the preceding members. You can cast your `(a.data_ + sizeof(all preceding members))` to the type of `someMember` and dereference that; but it's an ugly and unsafe solution.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't really understand your question properly.

But from what I understand, I can only say that an incomplete type can be used as `pointer` only in your code.

```
struct A; //incomplete type, since it has not been defined yet!

A *pA; //okay - pointer to an incomplete type is allowed!
A  a;  //error - cannot declare an automatic variable of incomplete type!
```

I hope this information would help you finding the *actual* solution to your problem!

Comment: It can be used as a `boost::shared_pointer<A>` too, by some boost magic: the destructor of `A` is not needed because it will be passed as a deleter at construction time of the shared pointer. Smart.

Comment: @Alexandre C: I was pretty surprised the first time I remarked that, the type erasure used for the deleter is simple yet impressive too. It's the kind of thing you want in your toolbox :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one very simple solution, if you only need access to `someMember`: provide a private getter, with an out of line definition.

```
class A {
private:
  friend B;
  int getSomeMember() const; // defined in .cpp

  struct IncompleteA;
  boost::shared_ptr<IncompleteA> data_;
};

class B {
public:
  void SomeFct(A& a) {
    a.getSomeMember();
  }
};
```

Comment: Because I specifically said getters are not good in this case because the expose implementation.

Comment: @Paul: a private getter will not expose anything more. And you are using friend classes, so you expose implementation already.

Comment: @Paul: if you need to use `someMember`, then you need to know its type, whether you get it via direct access or a getter. On the other hand, the getter *hides* the details of `IncompleteA` to `B` so it *increases* encapsulation. Also note that it's private and thus only exposed to `A` itself and `B` (since it's a friend).

Comment: @Alexandre C: Friends don't expose implementation. If they are used correctly they enhance encapsulation. Although I haven't shown any code, I can assure you this is a case where they do enhance encapsulation.

Comment: @Matthieu M: The purpose of the incomplete type is to eliminate all traces of any third part library being used from the header file. Having a getter (even private) defeats the purpose of the incomplete type in the first place. I'd rather just make a new header with a new class `AImplementation`, or something.

Comment: @Paul: what you showed us is best solved with a private getter. `IncompleteA` should be a class owned by you which bridges the third party class.

Comment: @Alexandre C. What I showed you is a sketch to describe the situation I find myself from a technical point of view. A private getter (that supposedly returns an instance of the third-party type) defeats the purpose of the incomplete type. Why not simply have the type defined in the header and make it complete, then? Or, why should I have a private type at all; why not use the third-party type directly?

Comment: @Paul: We're not arguing that the solution presented here is the best in your situation, but I do think it is the best in the sketch you presented. Note that the value returned by the private getter need to be an internal of `IncompleteA`, it is simpler but it could perfectly be a proxy or anything that is shared between `A` and `B`. That's one advantage of using a method rather than a direct access to the attribute.